# Can ActionScript 3 reads windows registry key?

Tags: actionscript-3

Can ActionScript 3 reads windows registry key? If it can't, is there a way to achieve the same purpose. I need to come out with a CD Menu that comes with option to install multiple applications. As such, I need to check the registry to determine which application has already been installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can't do it from a normal .swf.  As for Adobe AIR, see here: [Can you access the windows registry from Adobe Air?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666/can-you-access-the-windows-registry-from-adobe-air)

You'd probably be best off with a standard Windows installer application instead of Flash.

Comment: Yes, I am now using VC++ to do this.